How does the Taylor series represent the original function?
I see at $x=a$ the series will evaluate to the first constant $a_n$ for $y$.  So this should be the value of the original function centered at $a$. After this I’m lost. I'm trying to understand this better and the two articles I have read here and here don't seem to cover this. Is there some other resource which explains this better? Some proof?
I.e.
Power Series:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \left(x - c\right)^n = a_0 + a_1 (x - c) + a_2 (x - c)^2 + \dots$
Taylor Series:
$\sum_{n=0} ^ {\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^{n}$
where:
$a_n = \frac {f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$

Most analysis textbooks should cover this. You’re right it’s not a trivial fact. Intuitively, for nice functions (analytic) countable local constraints actually constrain the entire function. The derivatives are these local constraints.

Note also, that for real valued functions you don’t actually get this. There are functions which are infinitely differentiable everywhere, but whose power series don’t agree with it on any non empty open interval.

For real functions, the infinite series turns out to be less useful than the finite partial sums (first $N$ terms), called Taylor polynomials. For these, there are two nice  and useful formulas for the difference between the function and the Taylor polynomial on a given interval.

Taylor series are rather wonderful and you shouldn't expect to see why it works immediately. To get intuition, try thinking about why it would work for a polynomial. For a proof you can look up Taylor's theorem in any calculus textbook and apply it to various functions.

Every function can be approximated as a polynomial. There are many different ways to construct such polynomials. A Taylor series is one of them. Taylor series are special in that they try to approximate a function as best as possible in a small region around a single point.
This ties in with infinitesimal calculus ("calculus") because said calculus is all about how functions vary in a small region. By taking successive derivatives, you can find the coefficients of a polynomial that would best approximate the function at a given point.
Some functions are "nice" and the best approximation at a given point actually is exact for some region around the point. These functions are called "analytic". A lot of functions you regularly work with are analytic, including all polynomials (as you might expect), exponentials, and logarithms. However, not all functions are analytic. For example, $e^{-1/x^2}$ cannot be approximated by a Taylor series around $0$.
In complex analysis, there is an idea of holomorphic functions. Complex analysis is like real analysis but for functions from complex numbers to complex numbers. A holomorphic function is a function with a complex derivative. Being complex differentiable (i.e. holomorphic) constrains the function more than just being differentiable does, and it turns out that a function is analytic if and only if it is holomorphic (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions).
In summary, not every Taylor series converges, and not every Taylor series that converges actually converges to the function it is meant to approximate, but a sizable fraction of the functions you will encounter do can be written as a Taylor series. To check if an arbitrary function has a Taylor series, you can try to extend it to a function on complex numbers. If such an extended function is differentiable, then your function can be written as a Taylor series.

“Every function can be approximated as a polynomial” I don’t see how this true. It is true for continuous functions by Bolzano-Weirstrauss, which is nontrivial. Unless you mean something different by approximate.

Given a function $f$ and a set $U$ and a metric $d(f, \cdot)$ on $U$, you can always approximate $f$ by elements $u\in U$ in some way. In this case the approximation is meant in a very algebraic way (agreement of derivatives at a fixed point) and not at all related to the particular closeness of the graphs.

@Malady, I was trying to be not-very-technical in the opening paragraph, though I agree that arbitrary functions are not a limit of polynomials. E.g., Any function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ whose graph is a dense subset of $\mathbb R^2$.
Regardless, "approximate" does not mean "the limit of" and I stand by what I said: Arbitrary functions can be approximated by a polynomial, though that approximation is necessarily a good approximation.

I won't prove Taylor's theorem properly, but maybe the easiest way to see it is to just equate the individual derivatives. I'm going to work with the Maclaurin series (i.e. the Taylor series where $a = 0$) to keep things neat. We'll start with an assumed power series expression for $f$ that looks like
$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots$$
and let's assume that everything is nice and convergent at every step of this process. Then we start with setting $x = 0$ which gives us
$$\begin{eqnarray} f(0) & = & a_0 + 0 a_1 + 0 a_2 + \ldots \\
& = & a_0 \end{eqnarray}$$
So clearly $a_0 = f(0)$. Now we take the derivative of both sides, and again look at $x = 0$:
$$\begin{eqnarray} f'(0) & = & \frac{d}{dx}(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots) |_{x = 0} \\
& = & (a_1 + 2 a_2 x + 3 a_3 x^2 + \ldots)|_{x = 0} \\
& = & a_1 + 0 a_2 + 0 a_3 + \ldots \\
& = & a_1 \end{eqnarray}$$
and that's where we get $a_1 = f'(0)$. Then we take the second derivative and we get
$$\begin{eqnarray} f''(0) & = & \frac{d}{dx}(a_1 + 2 a_2 x + 3 a_3 x^2 + \ldots)|_{x = 0} \\
& = & (2 a_2 + 6 a_3 x + 12 a_4 x^2 + \ldots)|_{x = 0} \\
& = & 2 a_2 \end{eqnarray}$$
so now we get $a_2 = \frac{f''(0)}{2}$. You can keep going, and you'll find that when you take the $n$th derivative you'll end up with $f^{(n)}(0) = n! a_n$, with all the earlier terms vanishing thanks to the derivative and all the later terms still having a power of $x$ attached which disappears when you set $x = 0$.
So the Taylor series gives you the power series whose derivatives match those of the original function, and Taylor's theorem essentially tells you that for sufficiently nice functions this is enough for the two to be equal.
